# Why do no browsers apart from Firefox support animated PNGs?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, png, opera

When I look into the list (http://caniuse.com/apng) of supported browser on animated PNG, I found that basically only Firefox support it. All the other major browsers don't support. Even the Opera which they once support it and they drop it on newer release.

I always thinking animated PNG is nice. But why is most browsers don't support it? What is the reason they not support?

Comment: This isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow as it invites speculation, and no one can know the answer except the developers themselves. A Google search turns up articles like this: http://www.quora.com/Google-Chrome/Why-doesnt-Chrome-support-animated-PNG-files that's likely the best you can find.

Comment: If you mean APNG, that's not standard PNG, it was rejected by the PNG people. http://osdir.com/ml/graphics.png.general/2007-04/msg00286.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google developers discussed it here:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-dev/2xvXNJMsgxc/2CJ9jl-jItcJ

Comment: Please add quotes here, to improve readability and prevent link rot.